# How do I react to my field's widget autocomplete selection?

Tags: javascript, ajax, entities

I'm building a custom field with autocomplete. The autocomplete runs against an array of objects that I keep in my modules PHP code. An item looks like:

```
  $phrases['s5'] = array(
    'title' => 'S5',
    'description' => t('Do not store in %1.'),
    'placeholders' => array(
      1 => array(
        'legend' => t('Specify the liquid to avoid.'),
      ),
    )
  );
```

After user selects a match that corresponds to that item, I need to insert its `description` into the widget form to provide a complete visual feedback. I also need to react in case the description contains a `placeholder` by showing the legend and showing/enabling a textfield for that. Of course, this behavior should take place not only during node creation, but also upon opening a node with existing information.

My guess is it should be done through javascript/ajax. Does Drupal provide a ready-to-use behaviour or should I provide it in my module's script?

I'm not expecting a thorough tutorial here (although such miracles do happen) but maybe somebody could point me to a module that does this sort of widget behavior, so that I could learn by example.